# Convert ML VectorUDT features from .mllib to .ml type for linear regression

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Spark cluster and I would like to implement linear regression by executing this code :

```
data = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .load("/FileStore/tables/w4s3yhez1497323663423/basma.csv/")

data.cache()  # Cache data for faster reuse
data.count()

from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

# convenience for specifying schema
data = data.select("creat0", "gfr0m").rdd.map(lambda r: LabeledPoint(r[1], [r[0]])) \
    .toDF()
display(data)

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["creat0", "gfr0m"], outputCol="features")

(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed=100)

trainingData.cache()
testData.cache()

print "Training Data : ", trainingData.count()
print "Test Data : ", testData.count()

data.collect()

from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression

lr = LinearRegression()
# Fit 2 models, using different regularization parameters
modelA = lr.fit(data, {lr.regParam: 0.0})
modelB = lr.fit(data, {lr.regParam: 100.0})


# Make predictions
 predictionsA = modelA.transform(data)
  display(predictionsA)
   from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
  evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(metricName="rmse")
  RMSE = evaluator.evaluate(predictionsA)
 print("ModelA: Root Mean Squared Error = " + str(RMSE))

# ModelA: Root Mean Squared Error = 128.602026843
 predictionsB = modelB.transform(data)
 RMSE = evaluator.evaluate(predictionsB)
  print("ModelB: Root Mean Squared Error = " + str(RMSE))

     # ModelB: Root Mean Squared Error = 129.496300193
  # Import numpy, pandas, and ggplot
  import numpy as np
 from pandas import *
   from ggplot import *


 But its give me this error:
```

> IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column features must
>   be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was
>   actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce.

After googling this error I found an answer that says:

use `from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT`

instead of

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
```

or

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
```

and a function:

```
  as_ml = udf(lambda v: v.asML() if v is not None else None, VectorUDT())
```

With example data:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors as MLLibVectors

df = sc.parallelize([
    (MLLibVectors.sparse(4, [0, 2], [1, -1]),),
    (MLLibVectors.dense([1, 2, 3, 4]),)
]).toDF(["features"])

result = df.withColumn("features", as_ml("features"))
```

But still I have the same error:

here some data :

cause ,"weight0","dbp0","gfr0m"
1,"90","10","22.72"
5,"54","10","16.08"
6,"66","9","25.47"
3,"110","11","32.95"
5,"62","11","20.3"
5,"65","8","28.94"
1,"65","8","15.88"
5,"96","8","38.09"
5,"110","8","41.64"
4,"68","8","25.85"
5,"68","7","37.77"
1,"82","9.5","16.25"
5,"76","10","37.55"
5,"56","","37.06"
1,"93","8","18.26"
5,"80","7.5","48.49"
1,"73","8","38.37"
4,"76","8","31.09"
1,"68","8","39.62"
1,"82","8","40.08"
1,"76","9.5","28.2"
5,"81","10","36.66"
2,"80","","47.1"
5,"91","10","16.59"
2,"58","8","49.22"
1,"76","7","38.98"
,"61","8","21.8"
5,"50","6","26.97"
1,"83","7","27.81"
1,"86","8","48.62"
,"77","6","46.78"
5,"64","6","34.17"
5,"58","6","38.95"
1,"73","6","7.63"
5,"86","8","32.46"
1,"50","6","35.98"
5,"90","7","32.26"
5,"42","7","17.3"
1,"88","7","25.61"
5,"110","",""
1,"84","6","31.4"
5,"68","8","53.25"
1,"96","8","52.65"
6,"74","8","40.77"
1,"70","9.5","22.35"
6,"54","8","20.16"
1,"52","13","32.61"
,"84","8","52.98"
5,"90","9","28.67"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, you just need to alias the `VectorUDT` from `pyspark.ml` :

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors as MLLibVectors
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT as VectorUDTML
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

as_ml = udf(lambda v: v.asML() if v is not None else None, VectorUDTML())

df = sc.parallelize([
    (MLLibVectors.sparse(4, [0, 2], [1, -1]),),
    (MLLibVectors.dense([1, 2, 3, 4]),)
]).toDF(["features"])

result = df.withColumn("features", as_ml("features"))

result.show()
# +--------------------+
# |            features|
# +--------------------+
# |(4,[0,2],[1.0,-1.0])|
# |   [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]|
# +--------------------+
```

Of course the resulting DataFrame `result` isn't ready to be passed to `LinearRegression` as it doesn't have a label column but I trust you'd know how to deal with that.

Comment: hello , i did it  but when i execute           :                                                 # Fit 2 models, using different regularization parameters
modelA = lr.fit(data, {lr.regParam:0.0})
modelB = lr.fit(data, {lr.regParam:100.0})   it give me IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce.'

Comment: its exact , but when i execut comands for fiting the model its give the same error

Comment: im working on spark databricks . but how can i send you all the code with data ? , this part of comment gives me a few characters not to exceed

Comment: i explain to you all , but if you tell me how can i send you all the data with code and explication . i think its will be more clear ???

Comment: I just need the code that you are executing on actual data that generates the error. You can use http://gist.github.com to share code and data then share the link in the comment.

Comment: i made modification and i think now i am more precise :)

Comment: all my code is executable but when i fit the model it give me the error

Comment: that s work very good, but it give me prediction on the basis of                 
      df = sc.parallelize([
    (MLLibVectors.sparse(4, [0, 2], [1, -1]),),
    (MLLibVectors.dense([1, 2, 3, 4]),)  
[0,4,[0,2],[1,-1]] 1 1
[1,4,[],[1,2,3,4]] 1 1
features             label prediction                                                             how can i applicat this on my data , and sorry because i am biginner

Comment: Thank you for your precision and your help

Comment: hello, no my dataset have 4 columns, and in reality i want to predict (gfr by dbp, weight, cause ) :

Comment: cause  weight0 dbp0 gfr0m
1 90 10 22,72
5 54 10 16,08
6 66 9 25,47
3 110 11 32,95
5 62 11 20,3
5 65 8 28,94
1 65 8 15,88
5 96 8 38,09
5 110 8 41,64
4 68 8 25,85
5 68 7 37,77
1 82 9,5 16,25
5 76 10 37,55
5 56  37,06
1 93 8 18,26
5 80 7,5 48,49
1 73 8 38,37
4 76 8 31,09
1 68 8 39,62
1 82 8 40,08
1 76 9,5 28,2
5 81 10 36,66
2 80  47,1
5 91 10 16,59
2 58 8 49,22
1 76 7 38,98
 61 8 21,8
5 50 6 26,97
1 83 7 27,81
 this is a part of my data

Comment: ok update your gist please and change those commas to floating points !